# Is there any easy numerical integration method for advection in a 2-d non-linear vector field?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

I am trying to simulate a fluid running through a 2-d rough landscape.  The landscape is represented by a regular grid, and heights are just given as values to each cell (0,1,2 m).

For the sake of this question we can think of the landscape being a hole with smooth border and the fluid starts at a border, falls through it, and fills the hole.

We can assume heights follow a Gaussian distribution centered in the middle of the grid, multiplied by -1. I want to be able to calculate how much liquid will be on each cell, at each time-step.

From what I could gather, my problem is essentially a numerical integration of an advection equation. I could find this simple definition of an advection equation for 1-d.

$${\partial p \over \partial t} = u*{\partial p \over \partial x } $$
where $u$ is the strength of the flow, $x$ is the x-coordinate and $t$ is time

with an easy to implement simple numerical solution based on upstream differencing:

$$ p_x^{t+1} = p_x^t + \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}u(p_{x}^t - p_{x-1}^t) $$

$t$ is just a label on this formula.

However, how can I change this formula for the 2-d case, and more importantly when $u$ changes depending on the cell, so we can add the rugosity of the cell?

I think we can turn height in a vector field to represent different values of  $u$ per cell (for example, using height differences between a cell and their neighbors). I also think we can use the MacCormack method to somehow do the numerical integration, since it seems to work with non-linear functions. But I'm lacking not seeing how to plugin this vector field and use this method correctly.

Comment: You might get better answers asking this on scicomp.stackexchange

Comment: Thanks I did not know of this community. I will keep the question here for a couple days. If I don't get an answer  I will migrate to scicomp.

Comment: You need to think of the physics more accurately. What you want are the shallow-water equations allowing for bed friction. These are three PDEs describing conservation of mass and two components of momentum. There are much better methods than MacCormack. Scicomp is the place to find out.